# Replace div content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few images that when you click on them, I would like a specific div text to appear underneath. 
This only works on the first click for some reason.

**scroll-content** is the div to place the content. **massage, zen, soul** are the image links. The **container divs** hold the `<p></p>` information.

```
      <section id = "image">
    <a href="#" ><img id ="massage"></a>...
       </section>
        <section id = "scroll-content">
            <div id = "container1">
                         ...
                     </div>
             </section>


 $('#massage').click(function() {

    var htmlString = $( '#container2').html();

  $('#scroll-content').html(htmlString);
});

$('#zen').click(function() {

     var htmlString = $( '#container1').html();
  $('#scroll-content').html(htmlString);
});


$('#soul').click(function() {

    var htmlString = $( '#container3').html();
$('#scroll-content').html( htmlString );
});
```

Comment: please share jsfiddle of it

Comment: jsfiddle pls, also is your jquery wrapped in a `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual working code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Nbn/2/)

Your example is not working more than one time because when you fire the instruction

```
$('#scroll-content').html(htmlString);
```

You are actually overwriting the content of the section where

```
 #container1, #container2, [...]
```

are stored.

```
<section id = "scroll-content">
            <div id = "container1"> //You are going to delete me.
                         ...
                     </div>
  </section>
```

You must change your code to add one dummy container.
as this:

```
 <section id = "image">
    <a href="#" ><img id ="massage"></a>...
       </section>
        <section id = "scroll-content">
            <div id = "dummy_container">
                 ...
            </div>
            <div id = "container1">
                         ...
                     </div>
             </section>


 $('#massage').click(function() {

    var htmlString = $( '#container2').html();

  $('#dummy_container').html(htmlString);
});

$('#zen').click(function() {

     var htmlString = $( '#container1').html();
  $('#dummy_container').html(htmlString);
});


$('#soul').click(function() {

    var htmlString = $( '#container3').html();
  $('#dummy_container').html(htmlString);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing html under `scroll-content` div which has all `container` `div`s and hence getting lost after replacing html, thats why it is working for first time.

Instead of this, just make show / hide `container` `div`s which is inside `scroll-content`.

Like below :

```
$('#massage').click(function() {
   $('[id^="container"]').hide();
   $('#container2').show();
});

$('#zen').click(function() {
  $('[id^="container"]').hide();
   $('#container1').show();
});


$('#soul').click(function() {

   $('[id^="container"]').hide();
   $('#container3').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want new content to appear underneath the previous content, you have to `append` new content. `html()` will replace previous content.

```
$('#massage').click(function() {
    var htmlString = $( '#container2').html();
    $('#scroll-content').append(htmlString);
});

$('#zen').click(function() {
     var htmlString = $( '#container1').html();
     $('#scroll-content').append(htmlString);
});


$('#soul').click(function() {
    var htmlString = $( '#container3').html();
    $('#scroll-content').append( htmlString );
});
```